# Getting those rows from a table where status is still the same some days later?

Tags: mysql

I got a MySql table with 3 columns `status, mail and created_at`. Now I would like to get those rows where `status = 'somestatus'` where the `status` is still 'some_status' for example 3 days later. It should be selected by column `mail`.

So if there is the same `status` 'somestatus' for the same `mail` 3 days later (in created_at), I want to select that data. Column `created_at` contains data in the form of **2016-08-01 14:13:27**

**If thats easier to fetch:** I need all rows for the same mail where the status was and is still 'somestatus'. As soon as the status was 'somestatus' and later changed to any other than 'somestatus', I do not want that data. Easier?

Comment: Do you want to retrieve all rows which did not change their `status` in 3 days? I suggest using a second column `status_changed_at` containing info on when was the last time status was modified (you would need to update it along with `status`).

Comment: I cant add any columns. I just need those rows (by column mail) for which the status is still the same 3 days later (according to created_at).

Comment: are all of these records available already (for example 2016-08-01, 2016-08-02, 2016-08-03, 2016-08-04). Or is this going into the future (so today +3 days)

Comment: The dates are all in the table already, I just need to select them somehow.

Comment: @Arnie You can't really do that without recording last status change date / history of updates.

Comment: yes you can do that @dmitryguzeev. I dont think you understand op's question

Comment: Do I understud you correct? When you create a new entry it get a fixed status ( lets say 'new' the create_at timestamp is set. After that the status may changed. So you look for a solution to get all entries where status = 'new' and created_at + 3 day > now()? If not you how you you determine IF the status has changed?

Comment: @Thomas: Exactly, there will be multiple entries for the same mail address with the same status, the only thing that differs is the timestamp (created_at).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checks records for `DATEDIFF` between @startDate (set this to whatever), and that + 3 days

```
SET @startDate = '2019-11-23';
SELECT status, mail, created_at FROM table
WHERE status = 'somestatus' AND
MAIL = 'some value' AND
DATEDIFF(@startDate, (@startDate + INTERVAL 3 DAY)) = -3
```

---

After updated question this should do the trick.

Check a sub query in your where. And go through all `Mails` that have a different value then `notpayed`.

```
SELECT status, mail, created_at
FROM test
WHERE mail NOT IN
(
SELECT mail
FROM `test`
where status != 'notpayed'
)
```

[dbfiddle.uk to support above query](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=a1cee58c5883d683255215612aef7fd1)

Comment: Thanks, but here I have to set the startdate manually which I cant, because its dynamic. Is there a way to set it dynamically in order to get the desired results?

Comment: What do you mean with i have to get the startDate dynamically? Earlier you said all dates were in the past so there is no corrolation between now and then

Comment: Yes, the dates are all in the database already, each in a separate row. But I need this to work without setting the start date. Like this: Return all rows where the mail is the same, status is somestatus and created_at is at least 3 days away from the previous created_at for the same mail.

Comment: is mail always 3 records of the same unique "id or along those lines". With a max of 3 records per unique mail?

Comment: @Arnie if you could show what your table looks like with some data in it, it could greatly improve our capability to help you

Comment: No, it could be 3 days away from the previous or 2 days and 3 days or 2 days and 4 days. This represents orders with created_at as order date. The status I am looking for represents a status where orders have been placed but could not be paid, so the customers (mail) orders again sometimes. Sometimes an order could not be paid, but the next time the customer tries, it worked and the status changes. 

So the reason for this is to find those cusomers that could still not pay 3 days later.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202702/discussion-between-arnie-and-tomm).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
a.Id,
a.Client_id,
a.Name,
a.date
FROM 
(
SELECT 
  Id as Id,
  Client_Id as Client_Id,
  Name as Name,
  Value as Value,
  date as date,
  row_number() over (Partition by client_id,name,value order by id) as row_num
FROM <your_table>) a
WHERE a.row_num = 1;
```

Comment: Try to explain what you have done in your solution, this will be a lot more helpful to other users rather than a code only answer

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `DATEDIFF` function which returns difference between two dates in days, like this:

```
SELECT status, mail, created_at
FROM tbl
WHERE status = 'somestatus' AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), created_at) = 3
```

Comment: Looks good, but does not work I think, thats becasue of the NOW(). It should always compare created_at with created_at. Something like `DATEDIFF(created_at, created_at) = 3`